# Is there a way to remove the space between the top of the screen and top of the image in ScrollView?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, android-scrollview

I wanted to display my super-tall image, so I tried to put it into ScrollView,and constraint it to the top of the screen so it would be possible to scroll through it. I imagined it would fill in the whole space on the screen but somehow there are two big blank spaces at the top and bottom of the image, so I can't pin the image right at the top

```xml
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/pozadid1"
    tools:context=".Lekce1Activity">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <com.ortiz.touchview.TouchImageView
                android:id="@+id/image1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/i1"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I tried messing up with all the constraints but I messed up. I think the constraints are the problem, but I can't figure it out. I tried also the "android:scaleType="fitStart"" thing but it breaks after some scrolling.

This is how it looks, there's just a background until you scroll down. After a while, the image finally appears.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: For visual problems, it helps to post a screenshot to show what you're describing. Also, have you tried debugging with the [layout inspector](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/layout-inspector)?

Comment: I've added the picture. I haven't tried the layout inspector, any tips about that?

Comment: My tip is to try using it :)

Comment: Why do you have a second constraint layout between the scroll view and image view? If that doesn't serve a purpose, get rid of it.

Answer (score 0):

Open the "Design" view to see your screen side-by-side with he Component Tree and then click through the Component Tree to see which part of your layout is adding the space. You'll see blue borders around the element you have highlighted and you can use that to narrow down your problem.

Comment: Well... I ended up using super big negative magical number (-3500). Not the best solution but it works!

Comment: Using a "super big negative magical number" doesn't "work" - it hides your real problem and will cause you more problems down the line (for example, did you test this on more than one device with different screen sizes?) Fix your actual problem.